# Fetch won't return any results

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have never used `fetch` before, and have followed the documentation, however, no results are being returned from my backend. When I submit the form, the url changes, and all appears fine in my console, but no response from my express backend.

The following code is what I have after my form in a script tag. Can someone please advise?

```
async function getSample(url = `http://localhost:3000/lookup/${url}`, data = {}) {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data) 
  });
  return response.json();
}


document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  event.respondWith(
    new Response(myBody, {
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: a) You don't call `getSample()`. b) `event.respondWith()` should be used with `FetchEvent`. c) `response.json()` also returns a `Promise`. d) You use `url` in the default value for `url`. e) Put a breakpoint or `console.log()` in the server, is it called?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman There is a ```console.log()``` in the server. By called, do you mean a ```.get```?

Comment: No, I mean that there isn't any call to `getSample()`

Comment: @ChayimFriedman not in my backend express server

Comment: In your frontend - this is the function that should perform the `fetch()`

Comment: @ChayimFriedman do you mean getSample should perform the fetch() in the front end? I will have to call it..,.

Comment: From what I see, yes. I don't see other `fetch()` in your code

Comment: @ChayimFriedman so I need two fetch requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a promise and then handling the value returned by the fetch with resolve and reject

```
async function getSample(url = `http://localhost:3000/lookup/${url}`, data = {}){

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data) 
          }).then(async response => {
               if (response.ok) {
                    response.json().then(json => resolve(json));
               } else {
                    response.json().then(json => reject(json));
               };
          }).catch(async error => {
               reject(error);
          });
    });

};
```

You would then call it like

```
getSample(...)
.then(results => {
     //Code when fetch is successful
}.catch(error => {
    //Code when fetch fails
};
```

I think the problem with it returning nothing is that `getSample` is an async function, but I imagine you're calling it within a program that isn't async, and so whatever code comes after `getSample` is using trying to use the value returned from `getSample`, but nothing's been returned yet, so it's using an empty value. Either that or the return of getSample is happening before the fetch completes. I'm not sure of the exact order that things happen, but a promise should fix your problem

Comment: Thanks!! My backend is async. Is the promise suited for that?

Comment: I imagine so. You can read the [mozilla docs on promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) if you like

Comment: [Here's a tutorial on promises](https://scrimba.com/learn/trickyjavascript/what-are-promises-c73a9PSk) and here's a [tutorial on fetch](https://scrimba.com/learn/trickyjavascript/fetch-cgK4r9c6). I like these tutorials because you can actually edit the code within the videos. Also, I noticed that you never seem to mark answers as correct. If answers solve your problem, you should click that checkmark next to the answer